# clipBorad with zClip doesnt work in some browsers

Tags: google-chrome, browser, load, runtime-error, zclip

I 'm trying to use Clipboard Copy for one page written in asp.net
I use zClip for browsers except IE , in some browsers(chrome most of the times), my button which do Clipboard Copy doesnt work, when I trace code with F12 in Chrome, this Error apears:

```
GET http://www.steamdev.com/zclip/js/ZeroClipboard.swf net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED
```

and for one other resource, this Error occurred

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
```

why some browsers cant Load these Files ???

thanks for Any help or suggestion .
:)

Answer (score 0):

It might be occurring due to browser and Flash security restrictions, the clipboard injection can ONLY occur when the user clicks on the invisible Flash movie. A simulated click event from JavaScript will not suffice as this would enable **clipboard poisoning**.

It has been mentioned as limitation of zclip plugin in its github repo.
Please refer to **[github link](https://github.com/zeroclipboard/zeroclipboard/blob/master/docs/instructions.md#limitations)** for more details

And for clipboard poisoning please refer to [**this link**](http://www.computerworld.com/article/2533706/security0/adobe-patches-flash-clickjacking-and-clipboard-poisoning-bugs.html)

**Also below are some points regarding zclip:**

“The ZeroClipboard library provides an easy way to copy text to the clipboard using an invisible Adobe Flash movie and a JavaScript interface”

**Advantages:**

1. Stylized the button
2. Easy to use and configure
3. Work well on Chrome, Firefox

**Disadvantages:**

1. No flash, no action
2. This clipboard injection can ONLY occur when the user clicks on the invisible Flash

Comment: @SarahN, are you fine with the explanation?